# Should I learn Spring before Spring MVC?

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

I know java well, and have some experience in EclipseLink, Hibernate, JSF, Grails and some other stuff. but now I wanna learn Spring MVC for web apps and maybe for the sites. and should I learn Spring Framework before begin Spring MVC, or not?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In short, yes. Spring MVC borrows a lot of concepts like dependency injection from Spring, so you need to burn these concepts in before learning Spring MVC. For example, just create a simple Java project, create a few beans, understand the concepts of how a container / injection / wiring work, and then move on to implementing them in Spring MVC.

The most obvious benifit is you can integrate Spring with other web frameworks that you might already be familiar with. That way you get the best of both worlds, and don't have to learn Spring MVC until you have to.

[This](http://blog.springsource.com/2010/11/09/green-beans-putting-the-spring-in-your-step-and-application/) tutorial explains connecting to a database the spring way, and explains basic Spring concepts while at it. You could then follow it up with the [Spring MVC tutorial](http://blog.springsource.com/2011/01/04/green-beans-getting-started-with-spring-mvc/).

Comment: thank u for your quick answer. now I know what I should read and the best place for beginning. best regards

Answer (score 0):

Spring has an easy learning curve, (not to master it of course) so I would suggest learning them together on a small-scale test project.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if the question is pertinent for stackoverflow, but in any case I think learning Spring MVC is the best way to take a first step to learn Spring, in fact many Spring tutorials start with a Spring MVC application.